# consuming a Spring mvc web service with jquery

Tags: java, web-services, jquery-mobile, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc Web service like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class helloWs {
    @RequestMapping(value= "/getObj",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
        User prueba(@RequestBody User user) {
        user.setEmail("sample_email@sample.com");
        user.setName("sample_name");
        user.setDeleted(true);
        return user;
    }
}
```

The jquery call to this Web service is in a html file wich contains the function:

```
function hellowsfunction() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"http://localhost:8080/ehCS-ui/rest/hello/getUser",

    dataType: "jsonp",

    success: function(msg) {
    $('#lblResult').html('<p> Name: ' + msg.name + '</p>');
     $('#lblResult').append('<p>email : ' + msg.email+ '</p>');
     $('#lblResult').append('<p> deleted: ' + msg.setDeleted+ '</p>');
        alert('Success: ' + response);



 },
  error: function (e) { 
        $("#lblResult").removeClass("loading");
        alert('failed:'+e);
        console.log(e);
         }
 });

}
```

And the result should be in a div like this.

```html
<div id ="lblResult" style="color:blue;">result   here</div>
```

The web service is ok, but it seems that Jquery doesn't read the json obectj: This is a user object that web service returns on the browser.

```
{"version":null,"deleted":true,"insertDate":null,"updateDate":null,"owner":null,"userId":null,"name":"sample_name","surname1":null,"surname2":null,"login":null,"collegiateNumber":null,"nif":null,"email":"sample_email@sample.com","surname2Required":null,"telefonNumber":null,"birthDate":null,"inactive":false,"inactiveReason":null,"inactiveDate":null,"position":null,"professionals":null,"applications":null,"areas":null,"sexType":null,"locale":null,"password":null,"id":null}
```

But my javascript console show me this error all the time, and I don't know what is wrong.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
>
> In line 1 of the response.

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you're returning is JSON, not JSONP.

JSONP is JSON with padding, that is, you put a string at the beginning and a pair of parenthesis around it. For example:

```
//JSON
{"name":"stackoverflow","id":5}
//JSONP
func({"name":"stackoverflow","id":5});
```

http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2011/10/json-vs-jsonp/